# How to convert text image to word converter?

Tags: image, cpu-word

I have searched many ways for free software but no results.I am having TIFF text image and i have worked with foxit reader but there is no editing options.Is there any idea for image converter tool or i want to purchase?Give me idea ? Please help?

Comment: Search for *optical character recognition*.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified what OS you use and if you are looking for source code to automate the word extraction so I will assume you have Windows and a bunch of images you want to extract text from. Therefore a quick solution would be to have a Microsoft Office CD and install the Microsoft Office Document Imaging component which performs OCR on images. In this way you can extract text. More info found here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/help/about-microsoft-office-document-imaging-HP001077103.aspx

Comment: I am using Windows xp and ms office 2007.

Comment: here is a PDF explaining how to install Document Imaging on MS Office 2007 [link](http://lis.dickinson.edu/Technology/Training/Tutorials/ms2007/misc/doc_imaging.pdf) and here is how to use it [link](http://lis.dickinson.edu/Technology/Training/Tutorials/ms2007/misc/doc_imaging_edit.pdf)